# How to run an apk in the chromium browser using a plugin?

Tags: software-installation, android, chromium, browser, chrome-extension

Using a [plugin](https://www.apkonline.net/) for an `android` emulator, how do I run an `apk` which has been downloaded?

It's easy enough to click "run online" for, example, `twitter` -- but not all the apps have this option.

for example:

https://www.apkonline.net/download-android-apks/app-microsoft-word

Comment: Third party software is on topic per site rules, Chrome browser is third party software

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Yes the plug in is on topic, I believed it was just a web site. I provided the OP an answer and cleaned up.

Comment: @Nicholas Saunders: I downloaded `Android 9.0-R2 (64bit).vdi`. It works pretty good in VirtualBox, not much setup required.. I think I will also give Mark Kirby's method a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install and run an APK via this extension, you can use its built in file browser.

First click the extension icon in your toolbar and choose "My apk manager & apk upload".

On the page that opens is a small blue upload arrow, click it

[image]

Choose browse and provide it your apk, it will start to upload.

Once it is finished the apk will appear in the library view (just above the upload arrow)

[image]

Now you can click on the run apk option to run your apk on the emulator. You must open the app draw in the emulator and click on you installed app to run it.

Comment: pardon, wwhat does "library view" refer to?  On my GUI, the files browser gives the `apk` an android icon, but treats it as an archive to unzip.  The library is in the plugin?

Comment: Like in the second screen shot @NicholasSaunders  I was on Firefox does it look different for you?

Comment: huh.  not sure.  I'm uploading an `apk` to their cloud, and think I'm in the library.  I think that answers the q, but let me confirm before I click the accept button. thx.

Comment: Oh, the view does not show like that until the upload is finished, it is just on the same page. Yes certainly make sure it works first :)

Comment: yeah, the app I want keeps crashing but I get the idea.  let's just say that the ads motiviate me to just run the emulator directly.  thx.  it's not really a "plugin" as I think of a plugin, btw.